How to make a where query on a firebase subcollection?
I'm a bit puzzled by how firestore works. I have been reading the documentation and forums, but it remains unclear.

I have a "leads" collection, then a ${admin_id} sub-collection, then a document.
I'd like to query all documents within the sub-collection where "coordinate.geohash7" is in an array of geohash7 strings.
The current code :
      import database from '@react-native-firebase/database';
      import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';

      firestore()
        .collection('leads')
        .collection(admin) // @ERROR: Property 'collection' does not exist on type 'CollectionReference<DocumentData>'
        .where('coordinate.geohash7', 'in', [user_geohash7, ...neighboring_geohashes7])
        .onSnapshot(
          async (snapshot) => {
            const leads: Lead[] = [];

            snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
              const lead: Lead = { id: doc.key, ...doc.val() };

              const distance: number = calcDistance(
                user_location.latitude,
                user_location.longitude,
                lead.coordinate.latitude,
                lead.coordinate.longitude
              );

              if (distance < 1)
                leads.unshift(lead);
            });

            await setLeadsList(leads);
            await queryClient.invalidateQueries(['leads']);
          },
          handleError
        );

I had a simpler query before adding geohash:
      import database from '@react-native-firebase/database';
      import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';

      database()
        .ref('leads')
        .child(admin)
        .on('value', async (snapshot) => {
          const leads: Lead[] = [];

          snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            leads.unshift({ id: doc.key, ...doc.val() })
          })

          await setLeadsList(leads)
          await queryClient.invalidateQueries(['leads'])
        });

From what I have read, it seems like it cannot be done on Firebase...
I could create another collection called "geohashes" that would list all documents.
-> but then I would have to duplicate the documents...
I could create another collection called "geohashes" that would list all documents ids
-> but then I would have retrieve them within the sub-collection with a where clause so same issue
What are your thoughts on that ?
Is such a query even possible on Firestore ?
Should I opt for another strategy ?
Thanks in advance !

You no longer need geohashes to perform geoqueries on Firestore. See https://medium.com/p/6c2f10fd285f

@FrankvanPuffelen Thanks ! How can I make a 4x where query on a sub-collection ?

What is the exact query you're looking for?

Hmmm... you've tagged with google-cloud-firestore, but the screenshot in your questions show the firebase-realtime-database. While both are partt of Firebase, they are completely separate products. I guess that's also why the first query will not work: the Firestore API will not connect to the Realtime Database.

The screenshot in your picture is of data in the Realtime Database, The first sample is trying to read from Cloud Firestore. While both of these databases are part of Firebase, they are completely separate and the API from one cannot be used to access the other one.
There are no collections, no subcollections, and no documents in that screenshot. Just nodes (leads, $adminid, and $pushid) and then properties for the push ID.
Also note that your screenshot does not show any coordinate.geohash7 property, so it's hard to say how to query that or whether it's even possible. One thing to keep in mind is that Realtime Database's query capabilities are quite minimal, and it does not support anything like a "where value in array" type condition.

Hi !
Indeed, for now, our data is stored in the Realtime Database. We will migrate it to Firestore later.
The main issue is about getting to the $pushid node to perform the where query.
firestore()
.collection('leads')
.collection(admin) // @ERROR: Property 'collection' does not exist on type 'CollectionReference'
